# how to enable and take WTF_LOG in chromium[Android]

Tags: android, chromium, webviewchromium

I have seen any logs written in WTF_LOG(Media,...) in chrome code. after lot of code search I didn't any way to enable and take these logs for android platform,
I find a useful link on chromium official site, but there is not information for android platform
https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging

I have the chrome build able code for android platform . I want to check these WTF_LOG

Answer (score 1):

As per comment in src/third_party/WebKit/Source/wtf/Assertion.h:259

WTF_LOG has been deprecated, and it should be replaced with DVLOG() or VLOG()

reference: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/wtf/Assertions.h&q=WTF_LOG&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=259